# How do I get NavigationController functionality without subclassing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So my app's core is a tab bar. In each of 3 tabs is a UINavigationController subclass. Each one has a different type of table in it, which when a row is tapped, a detail is shown etc.

I currently have a 3 separate subclasses of UINavigationController, one for each tab. Then when a new tab is pressed, the table's controller is pushed.

I just read that you're not supposed to subclass UINavigationController. I'm not overriding any of UINavigation Controller's functionality, but I am overriding it's UIViewController functionality in viewDidLoad.  Honestly that's just about it. It seems pretty silly, but Im unclear on how to get the Navigation Controller functionality without subclassing the way I have.

So how am i supposed to have a UINavigationController that I don't subclass? What is the approach that you're supposed to take to switch out the views when a tab is selected?

I'm pretty much a noob.  Will Apple reject my app for subcalssing UINavigationController if im only overriding viewdidload?

I've heard folks say not to subclass UINavigationController, and instead 'present it modally.' I have used modal presentation a little bit, but I honestly dont' quite get how it would apply...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing in `viewDidLoad`? What about do it in root view controller, not in navigation controller?

P.S. I think Apple will not reject your app for subclassing UINavigationController.

Comment: Since I'm loading different views into the initial view of the Nav controller, viewdidload is just allocing and pushing the right viewcontroller to display. Thanks for the ps btw!

Comment: As I understand, you have 3 tabs with navigation controllers in each. I usually implement it in the next way: create xib with UITabViewController, add UINavigationController into each tab and assign 3 different controllers as root controller of navigation controllers.

Comment: Oh i see! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should use categories to add extra functionality like that. It would look something like this:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (CustomViewDidLoad)

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //code goes here
}

@end
```

You can add this to the bottom of the file that initializes the navigationcontroller

More info about categories (at the bottom): http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/